# Horizontal Scalability

Tags: opendaylight

Is there any way in ODL to split the same namespace into a few shards? The current performance of our application for topology discovery does not satisfy us. It would be good if we could use a few controllers to do it. For this purpose, we would divide our controllers into two sets: frontend and backend controllers.  Each frontend controller would only collect and store the data from some subnet of the network to data store.. Each of the frontend controllers should use the same namespace but a different shard because we want it to be a shard leader for the high performance.  Backend controllers  would use the collected data. They should receive all data from all frontend controllers. Currently we don’t care about HA.
Is it possible with the current ODL?

If not, are there any plans to have horizontal scalability in the next future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently ODL clustering is centered around HA. There have been some building blocks put in place to do sub-sharding for scale out but none of the stakeholders that currently contribute to ODL are currently investing resources in horizontal scalability. If you have a strong interest and use case, the ODL community would welcome your contributions.

Comment: Will it be enough to create a customizable ShardStrategy implementation? A user will supply her own ShardStrategy implementation that will do all horizonat splitting. Can it work?

Comment: There already is a PrefixShardStrategy that is used with prefix-based shards. I believe these can be configured dynamically via the cluster-admin RPCs. These are the building blocks that were put in place to be able to do sub-sharding a while ago but I didn't work on it nor have ever used it so unsure of the state of it.